# Remote uploading of exe code and dynamic linking functionality for an embedded target

Tags: c, embedded, patch, remote-access, dynamic-linking

I am developing an application for an embedded DSP target (that is not supported by any OS) and the development is carried out using C. I have a simple application that has initialization and a infinite loop as follows :

```
 #include <>
 main (){

 initialize ;

 while (1){

   poll_timer_for_scheduling (); // use for timing 
   remote_link_to_receive_data();  // used to receive data 
   remote_link_to_transmit_data(); // used to transmit data

   switch (sel) {
    case '1':
           function1();
    case '2':
           dummy_function(); // to be replaced by function2() later
    }


   }

 } // end of main

//-------------------------
 function1()
 {

 // some code

 }

//--------------------------
dummy_function()
{

 // NO code; just an empty function to be replaced later by function2()
}
```

Now, I compile and dump the executable in to the DSP target, which runs perfectly. The     dummy_function() is a function that I want to replace later remotely by     function2() as the system may not be accessible. This is similar to online patching of application but the application has to run in the target to perform self-patching.

So my requirement is update the executable with additional functionality (to cater to unforeseen conditions) later during the operational phase.  How do I compile a c function  function2() and upload the executable to the dummy_function()?

I am looking for a simplified version of dynamic linking functionality in the application. Are there some simple mechanisms to achieve this?

Comment: Is a bootloader a possible solution for you? So you could replace your complete application at once and it's much easier to build the application than create only linkable functions

Comment: @Jeb : Thanks for your reply. I am trying a slightly different but similar idea; I am including a functionality to copy the whole source code i.e duplicate the code to another memory location ( i call them prime and backup ) where the prime will patch the backup code with the additional functionality and switch the control to the backup. I will update this mechanism in my question as on of the possible technique /solution.

Comment: Probably your biggest practical question is if you will allow dependencies on the existing code (library functions, etc) or if you will make your delivered code entirely stand alone once control transfers to it.  If you allow dependencies, will you do so by fixed address, or by runtime symbolic name lookup, ie your own little dynamic linker?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use pointers to functions to later switch the implementation in a safe and atomic way. So initially the pointers could all point at the same single no-op dummy function. During the update, you would have to load code for the new function into memory, then switch the pointer to point at the location of the function in the newly loaded code.

I guess the tricky part might be not the patching of the function, but compiling that function so that it can be loaded later on. On most desktop platforms, dynamically loading code means performing relocations and stuff like that. Not sure how your DSP works in this respect. But simply recompiling the whole project and extracting the changes from that might not be feasible.

Comment: you are right. The independent compilation of the function is tricky and i don't have a way out yet. But if I compile the whole application by constraining each modules/function to specific section of the memory ( supported by the compiler), I can mange  to place the dummy_function in a way (at the end) such that the changes between the original app and the new app compiled with function2() is possible by appending the function2() codes to original app and switch the pointers appropriately.